# .net periodically execute a method

Tags: c#, .net, timer

By the time I click a button to execute a method named as `sendData()`, it works fine.
I need to execute it periodically when the application starts.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendData();
}

private void SendData()
{
    //some code and logic
}
```

I changed my code to the following, but it doesn't work, no error message is shown:

```
public partial class someForm : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer mtimer;

    public someForm()
    {
        mtimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        mtimer.Interval = 100; //1ms
        mtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnReadTimer);  
    }

    private void OnReadTimer(object sender, EventArgs eArgs)
    {
        if (sender == mtimer)
        {
            SendData();
        }
    }

    private void SendData() {}
```

Comment: You never start your timer. (mtimer.Start())

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.start.aspx) Method in order to make the timer *start*  ticking

```
mtimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
mtimer.Interval = 100; //1ms
mtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnReadTimer);  
mtimer.Start()
```